# MVC2 VS custom built framework

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

We are planning to start a new Sale Management System which will have about 12 subsystem.
We will use MSSQL2008 as a database.
We have got custom framework for ASP.NET that was built about 3 years ago which is not MVC type... And i am planning to move to MVC2 Framework.

### My Questions are

- What will be the big advantages of moving
  to MVC2?
- How about the learning curve for MVC2 and will there be any good
  guided study flow?
- We are planning to use Multirow (Instead of Grid View), inputman (For function key event and validation) from [grapecity](http://www.grapecity.com/japan/support/database/dotnet_productlist.htm) and ActiveReport.. Will they be easily fit into MVC2 Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have some good questions, but I think you have abused the question asking here.  You will find that people will be more apt to answer if you divide your bullets into their own questions.

Advantages of MVC?  Well pick up any MVC book and find those.  IMHO however it lets you get to more pure views.  It allows for separation of the main components of MVC (Model View and Controller) which allows you to test them.  For me its more than that.  I like how it allows for more control over what is in the view.  I get so sick of the ASP.NET rendered controls that break javascript.

Learning curve?  Well that all depends on how well you know HTML, Javascript, AJAX, and JSON.  If you dont know them well at all, you will have a bigger curve.  Now AJAX and JSON are not a must, but they will make it work better.  JQuery is MVCs best friend, learn it and live it.